# Is there a way to "try" Horizon Zero Dawn before I buy it?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I'm wanting to give Horizon Zero Dawn a try before I commit to purchasing it, but I can't find a demo anywhere and my current subscriptions (XBOX Game Pass and Amazon Luna) don't offer the title. So far, the only ways I've found to play the title are to purchase it outright from one of the following sources:

- [Playstation Store: $19.99](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/games/horizon-zero-dawn/)
- [Epic Games Store: $49.99](https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/p/horizon-zero-dawn-complete-edition)
- [Steam: $49.99](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1151640/Horizon_Zero_Dawn_Complete_Edition/)

However, none of these methods provide a demo of any kind (that I know of) prior to purchase which leaves me stranded to watch videos in order to make an informed decision. If possible, I'd like to actually ***play*** at least a small sample of the game prior to purchase. I'm okay if it's not possible, I just want to exhaust all options before I give up.

---

***Edit**: It turns out, similar to XBOX Game Pass, games are included with a subscription to PS Now and one such title happens to be Horizon Zero Dawn. I don't currently have a subscription to PS Now, but it turns out they have a free 7 day trial. In my **specific** case, this means I can **technically** try the game before buying anything. However, since this is has very specific prerequisites, I won't be posting it as an answer.*

---

Is there a way to "try" Horizon Zero Dawn before purchasing the title?

Comment: The funny thing is that Sony gifted HZD few months ago during the Play at Home period.

Comment: @pinckerman oof lol  just my luck :D

Answer (score 3):

For a good amount of years, demos are not a very common thing. So no, there is no 'just try this vertical slice of HZD and see if you like it'.

But there is a way: Abusing the self refund policy of Valve.

Their policy: [...] issue a refund for any title that is requested within 14 days of purchase and has been played for less than 2 hours.

PSN's refund policy stops as soon as you install the game, so you can't do so on PSN.

Comment: FWIW about the refunds - It can be a little iffy sometimes. I've had requests of 1.5 hour playtime declined, but ones of 2.5 accepted.

Comment: @n_plum that's unfortunate, I had a 40+ hour one accepted on the grounds that the game never actually opened, just ran the processes in the background. YMMV on the support rep I guess

Comment: Yeah it totally varies. Also FWIW - HZD is a fantastic game imo

Comment: @n_plum Red head with a bow - what more can you ask for? :P